# Simulate Mac (OSX) Safari on windows

Tags: cross-browser

Basically I have made a very visual site with the Scrollorama Jquery plugin and more, it looks and functions great on Firefox but not on Safari on windows.

Will it look weird on Safari on Mac aswell as Safari on windows or will it look and work just like on firefox? I have seen some other differences between safari on windows and on mac such as smooth scrolling for example.

My question is basically, can I depend on the site looking good on Safari on mac if it looks good on Firefox? I only need it to work on Safari and Firefox atm. Or is there any way of simulating Safari for Mac on windows?